# Linking .h file in GCC

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm probably missing something really stupid here, but I have the following:

```
#include <clapack.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "This is a test";
    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting the error message: `fatal error: clapack.h: No such file or directory`

I tried using the following command:

```
g++ test.cpp -L /usr/lib/liblapack
```

But still returns the same error. Doing a search for "clapack.h" found that it was in the following directory: `/usr/include/atlas/clpack.h`

But, linking that directory using the `-L` command does not work either.

Anyone suggest to where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is with include paths, not library paths. You need to either add the include path with `-I/usr/include/atlas`, or include like this:

```
#include <atlas/clapack.h>
```

assuming `/usr/include` is already in your path (which it most likely is).

I recommend you add some more compiler flas to get sensible warnings and errors. This is a typical set I use:

> -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-missing-field-initializers -pedantic-errors -std=c++11

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Got the same error message `atlas/clpack.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: You made a typo.. clapack.h not clpack ;)

Comment: @user1326876 I had copied it from the typo in your question :)